# Undefined offset: 0 in mail_queue.php | CentOS Web Panel

Tags: php, centos, postfix-mta

I am using Postfix. The mails are being sent and received properly but I am getting below PHP notice on CentOS Web Panel's mail queue page:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
>   /usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/resources/admin/modules/mail_queue.php on
>   line 0
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
>   /usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/resources/admin/modules/mail_queue.php on
>   line 0

Below is the content of /usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/resources/admin/modules/`mail_queue.php`:

```
<?php //003ed
// Copyright CentOS WebPanel, Decoding is FORBIDDEN
// All Rights Reserved. www.centos-webpanel.com
if(!extension_loaded('ionCube Loader')){$__oc=strtolower(substr(php_uname(),0,3));$__ln='ioncube_loader_'.$__oc.'_'.substr(phpversion(),0,3).(($__oc=='win')?'.dll':'.so');if(function_exists('dl')){@dl($__ln);}if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();}$__ln='/ioncube/'.$__ln;$__oid=$__id=realpath(ini_get('extension_dir'));$__here=dirname(__FILE__);if(strlen($__id)>1&&$__id[1]==':'){$__id=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__id,2));$__here=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__here,2));}$__rd=str_repeat('/..',substr_count($__id,'/')).$__here.'/';$__i=strlen($__rd);while($__i--){if($__rd[$__i]=='/'){$__lp=substr($__rd,0,$__i).$__ln;if(file_exists($__oid.$__lp)){$__ln=$__lp;break;}}}if(function_exists('dl')){@dl($__ln);}}else{die('The file '.__FILE__." is corrupted.\n");}if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();}echo('No Loader is installed. Please contact support.');exit(199);
?>
some encryption key here
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: if you will show code then only we can tell how you can resolve it? otherwise we can't help

Comment: @Anant which code do you want me to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, `sendmail` was causing the issue in my case. Someone from CWP support fixed it by uninstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

edit some symbolic links in /etc/alternatives

BEFORE:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 18 ene 31 21:42 mta -> /opt/exim/bin/exim
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 18 ene 31 21:42 mta-mailq -> /opt/exim/bin/exim
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 18 ene 31 21:42 mta-newaliases -> /opt/exim/bin/exim
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 18 ene 31 21:42 mta-rmail -> /opt/exim/bin/exim
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 18 ene 31 21:42 mta-sendmail -> /opt/exim/bin/exim
```

AFTER:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 26 feb  1 00:29 mta -> /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 22 feb  1 00:33 mta-mailq -> /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 27 feb  1 00:08 mta-newaliases -> /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 43 feb  1 00:11 mta-newaliasesman -> /usr/share/man/man1/newaliases.postfix.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 22 feb  1 00:31 mta-rmail -> /usr/bin/rmail.postfix
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 26 feb  1 00:30 mta-sendmail -> /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
```

EXAMPLE:

1. rename a symbolic link

   mv mta mta_
2. create a new symbolic link

   ln -s /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix /etc/alternatives/
   mv /etc/alternatives/sendmail.postfix /etc/alternatives/mta
3. ready. try using mailq